# Automatically updating local CSV on GitHub repo by Python Script

Tags: python, github

I have a project that is running a python script in a GitHub repo that reads and updates a local CSV file. Is it possible to save the updated CSV file on the GitHub repo using that py script? Calling and saving the file to my GoogleDrive won't work because it is a public GitHub repo, so I cannot store my Google credentials.

Does anyone have a solution? Or know a cloud provider that will read/write access to non-users accounts?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [PyGithub](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub), from their docs:

> PyGitHub is a Python library to access the GitHub REST API. This
> library enables you to manage GitHub resources such as repositories,
> user profiles, and organizations in your Python applications.

Or [GitPython](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html)

> GitPython is a python library used to interact with git repositories,
> high-level like git-porcelain, or low-level like git-plumbing.

Cheers!